# With FreeRadius I got error: Can't open PID file /var/run/radiusd/radiusd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory

Tags: oracle, centos7, freeradius

I am using Cnetos7 install FreeRadiusV3 with Database Oracle, unlucky Oracle database driver will not include by default(Oracle license reason), After googling I download and manual compile FreeRadius another version that contain Oracle driver module. My Centos have two Freedius.
With command

> systemctl start radiusd.service

## then I got error

```
Can't open PID file /var/run/radiusd/radiusd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear Everyone I got solution!

Because PID point to wrong directory that not match with radiud.config`[Service] Type=forking PIDFile=/usr/local/var/run/radiusd/radiusd.pid #This driectory should change to match with your PID that define in radiusd.config open it and check`
I hope it help other related other software beside Radiusd too!